# How to get the active index in easySlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [easySlider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) to create a slide show. but apparently it does not have a callback function or method to get the active index from it. Is there a way I can determine the active index from anywhere else ? if not how can I add this functionality to this plugin ? I'm not good at jQuery. any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *get* the current index without modifying the plugin code, you can use something like this:

```
var slider = $('#slider'),
    curIndex = Math.round(Math.abs(  parseInt(slider.find('ul').css('marginLeft')) / slider.width()  ));
```

To *listen* for the current index, you would need to modify the plugin code.